# "Argument list too long error" when I run any command in Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I run any command in Linux shell, I got "Argument list too long error", even when I use `vim` to open a file or use `sh` to run a shell script. Anyone knows?
Some commands to incur this error I ran is as follows:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
cat ~/.bashrc
python
which vim
```

Comment: Try setting `set -x` and see what else is going on.

Comment: What's the output of `env`? The limit applies to the combined length of your arguments *and* the environment. (Although if `python` causes the error with no args, `env` might also; you can try `set`--a builtin command--to see all variables that are set, although this will also include shell variables that aren't part of the environment.)

Comment: `env` incurs this error too.

Comment: I use `set -x` and then `ls`, it show `ls --color=tty` and incurs this error. The argument looks short

Comment: Assuming `set` shows (as I expect) a variable with a particularly large value, you can use the built-in `unset` to clear that variable from memory; that should allow you to get working long enough to figure out how that variable was set in the first place and prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Also, read https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/. Nothing there will help you fix this particular problem, but the information is illuminating.

Comment: I use `unset ls` but using `ls` has the same error. And `ls` command shows `ls --color=tty bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long error`

Comment: You can use `while read -d'' line ; do echo "$line"; done < /proc/$$/environ` to display the environment.

Comment: `ls` isn't a variable; it's a command name.

Comment: I use `while read -d'' line ; do echo "$line"; done < /proc/$$/environ`. It shows `+ read -d line
+ echo ''

+ read -d line
+ echo ''

+ read -d line
+ echo ''

+ read -d line
+ echo ''

+ read -d line`

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `set` (not `set -x`, which just toggles a setting and doesn't produce any output) yet? A handful of empty lines from hek2mgl's suggestion seems harmless, but at the same time is really not expected and suggests something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: Try running commands prefixed with \ i.e. "\ls" and see if you get the same results

Comment: You might check the resource limits in your current shell, via the `ulimit` builtin. You may have inadvertently set something like stack size (`ulimit -s` setting) very small, preventing your shell from being able to do much. `ulimit -a` lists all current settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all. I use `set`, which is suggested by chepner, and see what happened. The problem is caused by my environment `PATH`. `PATH` is too long. After I clear `PATH` and set it again. It works. 
Thank you